# Can't get this session to work properly

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm trying to set up a session in the application, but it doesn't seems to work properly. After I login, the session displays on Devtools but it doesn't redirect to `/index` as is suppose to do.

Here is what I've done:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash
from functools import wraps


app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "gr3hu39ud3n89ud893e4"


def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap


@app.route("/")
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid credentials. Please try again'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were just logged in!')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were just logged out!')
    return redirect(url_for('welcome'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

templates/welcome.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css.map">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome to flask</h1>
        <p>Click <a href="/">Here</a> to go home</p>
        {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
            {{ message }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css.map">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome to flask</h1>
        <p>Click <a href="/logout">Here</a> to go Logout</p>
        {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
            {{ message }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

templates/login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css.map">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Please Login</h1>
        <br>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{ request.form.username }}">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="{{ request.form.password }}">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Login">
        </form>
        {% if error %}
            <p class="error"><strong>Error</strong>{{error}}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<form>` in your login script did not have a `method` attribute. With no `method` attribute, `form` uses `GET` by default.

Try this in templates/login.html:

```
...
<form method="POST" action="">
...
```

Reference:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Comment: Oh god! I'm really ashamed. Thank you very much @Robᵩ.